# Android - Can't change action bar text colour

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design, android-theme

I'm trying to apply a custom style to the material theme action bar. Nothing fancy, just a simple change of title text colour, however I can't get the colour to change at all. I've set up a theme an app theme as follows in the themes xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?android:attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppBarLayout</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorTextLight</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorTextDark</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/colorError</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The action bar style which is referenced is defined in the styles xml as:

```
<style name="AppBarLayout" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppBarText</item>
</style>
```

The style which titleTextStyle references is also defined in styles xml as:

```
<style name="AppBarText" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorError</item>
</style>
```

I've tried other attributes in the latter style, such as:

```
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@color/colorError</item>
<item name="titleTextStyle">@color/colorError</item>
<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorError</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorError</item>
```

I've also tried applying the AppBarText style with other attributes to titleTextStyle, such as android:textAppearance. Alas - no luck.

How can I get this to change? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how Material components work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work but try this code once:

```
int labelColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.label_color);
String сolorString = String.format("%X", labelColor).substring(2); // !!strip alpha value!!

Html.fromHtml(String.format("<font color=\"#%s\">text</font>", сolorString), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE); 

getSupportActionBar().setTitle(colorString);
```

Comment: Did u try my answer ?